# Including php file as JS

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to change the image_list_url of tiny_mce to php file.

I changed the url to image_list.php file. It generated the exact output text same as the js file.

But even after giving same output it doesn't show's the image list.

I am wondering if the content-type is affecting it or not?

my JS file content:

```
// This list may be created by a server logic page PHP/ASP/ASPX/JSP in some backend system.
// There images will be displayed as a dropdown in all image dialogs if the "external_link_image_url"
// option is defined in TinyMCE init.

var tinyMCEImageList = new Array(
    // Name, URL
    ["Logo 1", "media/logo.jpg"],
    ["Logo 2 Over", "media/logo_over.jpg"]
);
```

my PHP COde:

```
<?php
    require('../../../system/config.php');
    $strPath = APP_ROOT.DS.'sys_uploads/images/';
    $objFileList = dir( $strPath );
    $arrFileList = array();
    while (false !== ($entry = $objFileList->read())) {
        if( is_file( $strPath.$entry) )
            $arrFileList[] = array($entry, ABS_URL.'/sys_uploads/images/'.$entry);
    }
    $objFileList->close();

    header('Content-type: application/x-javascript');
    //header('Content-type: text');
?>
// This list may be created by a server logic page PHP/ASP/ASPX/JSP in some backend system.
// There images will be displayed as a dropdown in all image dialogs if the "external_link_image_url"
// option is defined in TinyMCE init.

var tinyMCEImageList = new Array(
    // Name, URL
 <?php
    if( count( $arrFileList )>0 )
        foreach( $arrFileList as $dataRow ):
 ?>
    ["<?php echo $dataRow[0];?>", "<?php echo $dataRow[1];?>"],
 <?php endforeach; ?>
);
```

my PHP Output:

```
// This list may be created by a server logic page PHP/ASP/ASPX/JSP in some backend system.
// There images will be displayed as a dropdown in all image dialogs if the "external_link_image_url"
// option is defined in TinyMCE init.

alert('test working or not');

var tinyMCEImageList = new Array(
    // Name, URL
    ["Logo 1", "media/logo.jpg"],
    ["Logo 2 Over", "media/logo_over.jpg"]
);
```

Edit:

As per suggestion i even added a popup message too which even didn't show up.

Solution:

dun know what was error on my code but found good solution from link suggested:

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aexternal_image_list_url

Comment: Why do you count the size of `$arrFileList`? That's not required for `foreach` as long as it's an array.

Comment: i want to skip if its blank... thnx for suggestion... it helps me optimising my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As both the .js and your PHP file outputs are  identical, there should be no difference. `text/javascript` is the most widely supported mime type for JS, so using that might help.

It would also not hurt to name your dynamically generated JS files using a convention such as XYZ.php.js and using mod_rewrite to parse the php.js files as php.

Edit:

Also, per official [TinyMCE docs](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aexternal_image_list_url), please make sure that there is no whitespace before the `<?php` opening tag in the dynamically generated JS, also check for [UTF8 BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) which can be a sneaky cause of invisible output.

Comment: i tried adding header('Content-type: text/javascript'); too but it didn't helped... well abt second idea that's also great ... i will be trying it

Comment: How are you including the js file?

Comment: its just from tiny_mce script... ie. specifying it in options of tiny_mce_url list...

Comment: Could very well be the cause. Try doing what I suggested in second part of my answer and see if it helps.

Comment: about white space m pretty sure there isn't any. but how do i check UTF8 BOM

Comment: PHP Designer 7. Thnx it worked as per your link to tiny_mce documentation

Answer (score 0):

No need to change any headers. Just output the JavaScript.

js.php:  `alert("Working!")`

test.htm:  `<script type="text/javascript" src="js.php"></script>`

When I loaded test.htm, I got an alert box

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a problem of incorrect header type.

could you please change the line

*header('Content-type: application/x-javascript');*

to

*header('Content-type: application/javascript');*

As application/x-javascript is not a correct javascript header. Tell me if this thing helps