# .php Javascript File

Tags: javascript, php

**My question is - are there any significant drawbacks to using a .php file and telling the browser to interpret it as Javascript?**

Once it's rendered by the server, the content of the .php file would be entirely Javascript, however, tweaked slightly allowing for user permissions etc.

My main reasoning is that I don't want certain administrative functions to be at all visible to standard users (ie. those with prying eyes looking through the Javascript code).

I've seen here ([Including php file as JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548947/including-php-file-as-js)) that it IS POSSIBLE (technically) to achieve this, however it seems a little 'botchy' - has anyone had any experience with this practice?

Comment: Purpose of doing this could be getting data from the database as an JavaScript object or array. If so, then you can achieve this using `ajax` request too. Let us know your purpose to do so, so that one could guide you through...

Comment: if the browser can see the js, the user can as well

Comment: I did it and it worked. Surely this can be considered a trick. The main interest for me was the ability of use includes with javascript.

Comment: wherever you write your js, if it runs on browser then it will be visible to evry one who looks the resources/sources of the html page.

Comment: Your javascript code can be seen by anyone once your code is rendered through PHP in Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no significant drawbacks. Indeed this is one off the main purposes of PHP - to render text and code to be sent to the browser. There's not much difference between using PHP to echo out a few lines of javascript, and just having the whole file be javascript. The only benefit to using a PHP file for javascript would be the ability to embed PHP code, which is of course invisible to the user.